# pysox PTT digital voice recorder

Tags: python, sox

I need help.
I spent at least a day experimenting and failing to produce
this very simple sounding app.

PTT (Push To Talk) means any key starts a recording and any key stops it.
I want to assemble a library of recorded spoken sentences.
Start with:

- a choice of format (.wav, .ogg, .mp3, ...)
- a directory into which files go
- a list of sentences from which filenames are generated
- a text prompt to speak a sentence.

Preferred behavior:

- Text sentence appears in terminal window
- user hits a PTT button
- user speaks prompted sentence
- user hits a PTT button
- file appears in directory.

I anticipate the LLOC should be only a dozen or two lines long.
Here is framing code with one failed experiment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# This class is here just to support keyboard input.
from sys import (stdin, stdout)
from atexit import (register)
from select import (select)
from termios import (tcgetattr, tcsetattr, ICANON, ECHO, TCSAFLUSH)

class Raw(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fd = stdin.fileno()
        self.org = tcgetattr(self.fd)
        self.raw = tcgetattr(self.fd)
        self.raw[3] = (self.raw[3] & ~ICANON & ~ECHO)
        register(self.set_normal_term)
    def set_normal_term(self): tcsetattr(self.fd, TCSAFLUSH, self.org)
    def set_curses_term(self): tcsetattr(self.fd, TCSAFLUSH, self.raw)
    def putch(self, ch): stdout.write(ch)
    def getch(self): return stdin.read(1)
    def getche(self): ch = getch(); putch(ch); return ch
    def kbhit(self): dr,dw,de = select([stdin], [], [], 0); return dr <> []
    def __enter__(self): self.set_curses_term(); return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback): self.set_normal_term()

# This is the PTT recorder code.
from pysox import (CSoxStream, CSignalInfo)

def prompt(sentence, filename):
    print 'Hit any key to start recording.  Hit any key to stop recording.'
    with Raw() as raw:
        print 'Say: "%s".' % (sentence)
        while not raw.kbhit(): pass
        raw.getch()
        print 'Start'
        outfile = CSoxStream(filename,'w', CSignalInfo(48000,2,32))
        # Signal is to be collected until kbhit()
        while not raw.kbhit(): pass
        raw.getch()
        print 'Stop'
    outfile.close()

# This is the CLI to drive the PTT recorder code.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    prefix, ext = ['sentence', 'wav']
    sentences = ["hello world", "klatu barada nikto", "fubar" ]
    for sentence in sentences:
        filename = prefix + '.' + sentence.replace(' ', '.') + "." + ext
        prompt(sentence, filename)
```

Comment: It might help indicating what are you getting. An error? a crash? an earthquake?

Comment: This code records nothing.  The resulting file is 80 bytes long (empty).  I have tried to identify function calls to start and stop the actual recording of data.  It appears that once you launch a recording sequence you lose control of the session until it stops.  There are ways to trigger based on silence before and silence after, but I do not want that.  I want to record when I press to talk and stop recording when I press to talk again (or release the key).

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to pipe and then kill the pipe pid when finished.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# This class is here just to support keyboard input.
from atexit import (register)
from select import (select)
from termios import (tcgetattr, tcsetattr, ICANON, ECHO, TCSAFLUSH)

class Raw(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fd = stdin.fileno()
        self.org, self.raw = (tcgetattr(self.fd), tcgetattr(self.fd))
        self.raw[3] = (self.raw[3] & ~ICANON & ~ECHO)
        register(self.set_normal_term)
    def set_normal_term(self): tcsetattr(self.fd, TCSAFLUSH, self.org)
    def set_curses_term(self): tcsetattr(self.fd, TCSAFLUSH, self.raw)
    def getch(self): return stdin.read(1)
    def kbhit(self): dr,dw,de = select([stdin], [], [], 0); return dr <> []
    def __enter__(self): self.set_curses_term(); return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback): self.set_normal_term()

# This function handles prompts and keywaits
from sys import (stdin, stdout)

def prompt(pre, s, post):
    print '%s: "%s".  Press any key to %s.   \r' % (pre, s, post),
    stdout.flush()
    with Raw() as raw:
        while not raw.kbhit(): pass
        raw.getch()
    print ' '*79+'\r',
    stdout.flush()

# This is the PTT recorder code.
from subprocess import (Popen, PIPE)
from signal import (SIGTERM)
from os import (kill)

def collect(sentence):
    filename = prefix + '.' + sentence.replace(' ', '.') + "." + ext
    command = 'rec -q -r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 %s trim 0 2:00' % (filename)
    try:
        prompt('Preparing', sentence, 'start')
        pid = Popen(command.split(), stderr=PIPE).pid
        prompt('Recording', sentence, 'stop')
        kill(pid, SIGTERM)
    except:
        pass

# This is the CLI to drive the PTT recorder code.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    prefix, ext = ['sentence', 'wav']
    sentences = ["hello world", "klatu barada nikto", "fubar" ]
    print 'The following recordings must take less than 2 minutes of speech.'
    for sentence in sentences:
        collect(sentence)
```